# Looping asynchronous processes

Tags: go

When I write an application to process a list of files, I like to speed things up a little by making the processing and file reading parts run asyncronously. In shell, I used to background the processing function but precede it with a 'wait' to ensure any previous process is complete. I worked out a way to do this in Go using a buffered channel as a kind of mutex, but I can't help thinking that there must be a more elegant way. For instance, I have something like

```
rdy := make(chan int, 1)
rdy <- 1
for f := range fileList {
    data := MyReadFile(f)
    <-rdy
    go func() {
        MyProcess(data)
        rdy <- 1
    }()
}
<-rdy
```

I think there must be a way to use an unbuffered channel, but I can't figure out how to prime it into a 'ready' state before the first iteration of the loop. That is, the call to `<-rdy` in the first iteration of the loop must not block.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do a version of a producer / consumer pattern. See http://www.golangpatterns.info/concurrency/producer-consumer

Comment: Thanks, that's a great resource that I wasn't aware of. But actually my application can't allow the reading and processing to get out of step (to limit too much memory being taken by the data) so I think this is more like a semaphore scenario. And it looks, from here http://www.golangpatterns.info/concurrency/semaphores, like I'm pretty much doing an optimum implementation.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "out of step".  The producer / consumer model won't run away with your memory so long as you have: A sensible channel buffer size, and a sensible number of "workers" (consumers).  The example I linked shows only a single producer and single consumer and an unbuffered channel.  With that setup, the maximum number of "data" blocks in use at once would be one being actively used by the consumer, and one that the producer has created and is waiting to send.  If even that is too much, I don't see how any concurrent pattern is going to give you any benefit.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yes I mistakenly read that the producer and consumer were in a loop as well. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, looking at the producer/consumer example again, I think it has a slight flaw with respect to onward flow. Specifically, the consumer thread for the last produced item can still be processing after the `done` channel has received its message (because the processing in the consumer occurs _after_ the `msgs` channel has been received). So if the code after the `<-done` needs to use the consumed data then it may not see the last processed chuck. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you're right.  Unfortunately I've sent you a somewhat faulty example.  The solution is to have the producer close the messages channel when in is done sending jobs, and the consumer `range` over the channel to automatically break out of the loop when the channel closes.  This means your "done" signal can now come after the consumer loop ends, not when the producer loop ends.  If you are using multiple worker goroutines, you'll need to use waitgroups instead of a "done" channel

Comment: Take a look at my solution below. I left the consumer (which I want to keep as a single worker for my application) in the main thread and used a `close` signal from the producer in order to break out of the loop. I had thought I couldn't use `range` on an unbuffered channel, but it looks like you can, so I could simplify that consumer loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    files := []string{"0", "1", "2", "3"}
    data := make(chan string)
    
    wg.Add(len(files))
    for _, f := range files {
        go MyReadFile(f, data)
    
        go func() {
            MyProcess(data)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func MyReadFile(f string, data chan<- string) {
    data <- f // send file content
}

func MyProcess(data <-chan string) {
    content := <-data
    fmt.Println(content) // sample process
}
```

Where MyProcess waits until MyReadFile sends the content to the data channel and the wait group will ensure all the files are processed before continuing.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/_tsyZK8LvZv

Instead of passing string to the channel you can pass []byte. I hope this helped you, regards.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the sync package - that looks really useful.

Answer (score 0):

In light of the suggestion to check out http://www.golangpatterns.info/concurrency/producer-consumer , I attempted to write my code with this paradigm. However, I ran into the problem of the last 'consume' process not completing before the code flow continued. Thinking about how I need the 'produced' data to be 'consumed', I came up with this solution which seems to work (note that `datatype` is whatever happens to be the return type of the MyReadFile function):

```
pr := make(chan datatype)
go func() {
    for f := range fileList {
        pr <- MyReadFile(f)
    }
    close(pr)
}
for prdat := range pr {
        MyProcess(prdat)
}
```

So now the 'consuming' loop runs in the main thread and will complete when the `pr` channel is closed (which will be after all files have been read *and* processed) - I was pleasantly surprised to find that I could use `range` on an unbuffered channel like this (originally I was using the second, 'test', parameter in a channel assignment with an `if` statement to set the loop break condition - that works too but `range` is neater).

However, this does throw up an interesting question about the order of operations within a channel send statement. In this code, supposing the receiver of pr is not ready when `pr <- MyReadFile(f)` is encountered, will the execution of `MyReadFile` be blocked (i.e. will it not even start if pr is blocked), or will the statement block *after* `MyReadFile` has run and returned its data value (by which time the receiver may be ready)? Since I want the latter behaviour, I know I can force the order by splitting the statement like this

```
        data := MyReadFile(f)
        pr <- data
```

but I'd like to know if this is necessary.

Comment: About your order of operations question, this is easy enough to test https://play.golang.org/p/rgy7n-UTnKb

Comment: Thanks for that example. Since your Println does execute before the deadlock, it seems that the right hand side is fully evaluated before the state of the channel is assessed, which is as it should be, I'd say. So I think my solution above will work as desired.